# How to generate list of items with delete button after grabbing items from database using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am fetching some items from database which will have delete, edit buttons but don't know how to link delete or edit button with the particular item please help me.

```
<div class="feed-list-area">
    <div class="feed" id="1">
        <font class="feed-title">Website Title</font><br />
        <font class="feed-url">thisistheurlofwebsite.com/itisalwaysok</font>
        <input type="button" value="Delete" id="feed-delete" />
    </div>
    <div class="feed" id="2">
        <font class="feed-title">Website Title</font><br />
        <font class="feed-url">thisistheurlofwebsite.com/itisalwaysok</font>
        <input type="button" value="Delete" id="feed-delete" />
    </div>
    <div class="feed" id="3">
        <font class="feed-title">Website Title</font><br />
        <font class="feed-url">thisistheurlofwebsite.com/itisalwaysok</font>
        <input type="button" value="Delete" id="feed-delete" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#feed-delete').click(function(){
            //var id = $(this).closest('.feed').attr('id');

            alert('Delete');
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use font element. It as shouldn't be used at all and doesn't make sense here. Use div or p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Never** have more than one element with the same `id`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-types).

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rZunk/) with `id="feed-delete"` replaced with `class="feed-delete"`

Also, for random data you might want to use `data-` HTML5 attributes. Example:

```
<div data-dbid='3531'></div>
```

JQuery has a `data()` method to retrieve such data: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @RohitKhatri No problem. As @Anthony mentioned, do not use `<font>` tag, it is deprecated. Use the `<span>` tag instead. It does not impose any rules or looks by itself, but you can style it in your CSS